# How to find leaf nodes in the graph using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, amazon-neptune

[image: RDF Graph]

I have to find out all the leaf nodes of this graph with a generic query, this is because the leaf node is getting created from item X after 2 steps in some cases, in 1 step in some cases and in 3 steps in some cases.

Can someone help to write a generic RDF traversal query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will need is to look for all nodes what are not the 'subject' of any triple, i.e. that don't have an arrow coming out of them.

This is done with a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?b
WHERE{
?a :create ?b .
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?b :create ?c}
}
```

Comment: Hi Valerio, Thank you for your answer. I am new to SPARQL, this query is resulting in all such cases in my graph. Suppose I want all the final products from ITEM X - like in this case - item leaf 1, item leaf 2, item leaf 3. How to filter for such case?

Comment: I would do this:
`SELECT DISTINCT ?b WHERE { VALUES ?a { :ItemX } ?a :create+ ?b FILTER NOT EXISTS {?b :create ?c}}`
The `+` means 'a path of one or more instances of the property'.
So you will start at `:ItemX`, traverse the path and for each node in the path check that it is a leaf, and if so return it.

Comment: Thanks, but this query is giving me only the next nodes - that is items 1, 2 and 3 in this case. I think the query seems logically correct. Don't know why I am not getting leaf nodes.

Comment: Hard to tell why without seeing your data.
If your data is large, a good way to extract this subtree is this query:
`CONSTRUCT {?b :create ?c} WHERE {VALUES ?a { :ItemX } ?a :create* ?b . ?b :create ?c}`

Comment: Thanks, Using + worked. One more thing, If I want to select the full graph as it is then how to do it? Using + has removed any intermediate nodes when I run construct ( ?a creates ?b) where { ?a : creates+ ?b  }. How to get a full graph? ItemX -> Intermediate Nodes -> Leaf Nodes

Comment: I am able to do it in steps but I want a generic query -

Comment: The second query should work:
`CONSTRUCT {?b :create ?c} WHERE {VALUES ?a { :ItemX } ?a :create* ?b . ?b :create ?c}`